# jquery changes related to the fetching data within a div showing visibility hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to extract the price of an item selected with the following code, 
but now i have to hide the price in one select to show the prices in other select.

Based on the code below I have this

```
$('body').on('change', '.selectItemsList', function(){
    $price_value = $(this).text().trim().split('$')[1];
    $($(this).parents("tr:first").find('[name=getSelection] option')[1]).text('Default ($'+$price_value+')');
});
```

the following I the select

```
<select name="get_Items" id="get_Items" class="selectItemsList" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Choose Item" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <option value="128177000000982001~ACLS Heartcode Part 1 Online~YES~137.28">ACLS Heartcode Part 1 Online - &lt;div style=visibility:hidden;&gt;$137.28&lt;/div&gt;</option><option value="128177000000139503~ACLS Skills~YES~75.0">ACLS Skills - &lt;div style=visibility:hidden;&gt;$75.0&lt;/div&gt;</option></select>
```

Comment: you need to hide this `$(this).parents("tr:first")` ?

Comment: and where is tthe tr, u see i am inside the select which returns me json data

Comment: a little more code would be helpful

Comment: I have created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hiJWPr1ZOfQmHIhQALkj?p=preview) to see how your code works. You selected a value from dropdown using JQuery. Now what you want to do afterwards ?

Comment: i want to hide that part which div visibiltity in one of the select boxes and only fetch the middle price in the above jquery code, because price will still be there but it will not be visible in that select box

Comment: As I understand. You just want to see `137.28` instead of `137.28</div>ACLS Skills - <div style=visibility:hidden;>` in `$price_value` ?

Comment: correct. that is what i am trying to fix

Comment: Add this to your code `$price_value = $('.selectItemsList option:selected').text().trim().split('$')[1]`. I have updated the answer below. Please check if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$price_value = $('.selectItemsList option:selected').text().trim().split('$')[1]` to your function to achieve this

Please check this pluncker, I have updated it for you. See it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/EEkL0tmN42UUqbjAKUaS?p=preview).

> https://plnkr.co/edit/EEkL0tmN42UUqbjAKUaS?p=preview

**Your final code would be**

```
    $('body').on('change', '.selectItemsList', function(){
      $price_value = $('.selectItemsList option:selected').text().trim().split('$')[1]
      $($(this).parents("tr:first").find('[name=getSelection] option')[1]).text('Default ($'+$price_value+')');
    });
```

Hope this will help. Thank you.

Comment: I think `$(this).text().trim().split('$')[1]` needs to be `$('.selectItemsList option:selected').text().trim().split('$')[1]` to get the selected value's text.

Comment: the plunkr is wrong, what u are showing me, it does not show what i am trying to do, it still displays the div in options while i wanna hide it from user and work in background